# NSUserDefaults remove and set object from other thread

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
I'd like to understand why after removing an object from a background tread and then adding an object using the same key from main thread, it then becomes impossible to set it again from main. Is this a bug? or does it work as intended?

```
    let mykey = "nsDataKeyOne"
    let stringUno:NSString = "................."
    let dataOne = stringUno.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let stringDos:NSString = "000000000000000000"
    let dataTwo = stringDos.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()


    userDefaults.setObject(dataOne, forKey: mykey)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), {
        userDefaults.removeObjectForKey(mykey)
    })

    userDefaults.setObject(dataOne, forKey: mykey)

    print(userDefaults.dataForKey(mykey))  // print nil, why?


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), {
        userDefaults.setObject(dataTwo, forKey: mykey)
        print(userDefaults.dataForKey(mykey)) // there is data

    })
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Short answer

You are getting `nil` because the instructions are probably executed in the following order

```
userDefaults.setObject(dataOne, forKey: mykey)
userDefaults.setObject(dataOne, forKey: mykey)
userDefaults.removeObjectForKey(mykey)
print(userDefaults.dataForKey(mike))
```

### The reason

First of all, `NSUserDefaults` is thread safe. So we can imagine that a writing operation on a given key is performed when there is not another  thread that is changing that value.

When this instruction is executed
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), {
userDefaults.removeObjectForKey(mykey)
})

another thread start trying to add the closure to the global queue. While this thread is waiting to access the global queue the execution of your code does continue so this line is (probably) executed

```
userDefaults.setObject(dataOne, forKey: mike)
```

This line does lock `NSUserDefaults` until `dataOne` has been saved.

Next the closure is finally in the main queue and it's ready to be executed so

```
userDefaults.removeObjectForKey(mike)
```

And finally the print

```
print(userDefaults.dataForKey(mykey))
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not a bug. It is very likely that `userDefaults.removeObjectForKey(mykey)` was already executed by the `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH` queue *right after* you'd called `setObject(dataOne, forKey: mykey)` the second time so it has already been deleted at the time you want to print it out.

If you change the first `dispatch_async` to `dispatch_sync`, you'll see the data will be there when you print.